# How can I implement websocket in remix?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, remix

I am very new to remix and SSR, so I don't really understand how client js works. I have a websocket server written in GO and I was wondering if I could connect to that server directly from the client (as I would do in a SPA) or do I have to connect to express server first and then connect to my GO server? If someone could point me in the right direction that would be wonderful.